# How to generate next request ID

Tags: mysql, perl, sequence

I have a requirement, where request_id will be in the form of 
`REQ0000001,REQ0000002....REQ0000010, REQ0000011...., REQ0000099 REQ0000100.....` like first three char is REQ followed by 7 characters (number is sequence)... this request_id is the primary key in mysql table.

suppose last entry in table is REQ0000009, next entry wil be REQ0000010.. How to do it in perl??

I am using the following way:

```
$sql_query = "select request_id from requests order by request_id DESC LIMIT 1";
```

store this value in varibale named x.  then

```
$x = reverse $x;  #Reverse the String
chop $x; # Chop the last Character (here R)

chop $x; # Chop the last Character (here E)

chop $x; # Chop the last Character (here Q)

$x = reverse $x; # Again Reverse
$x = $x  + 1; # Add 1

if ( length($x) eq 1) # if length ==1{

    $NextReq_id = 'REQ000000'.$x;

elsif ( length($x) eq 2)


    $NextReq_id = 'REQ00000'.$x;

elsif ( length($x) eq 3)


    $NextReq_id = 'REQ0000'.$x;

elsif ( length($x) eq 4)
{

$NextReq_id = 'REQ000'.$x;
}
```

Is here any better way to do this?

Comment: How would you handle `REQ9999999`? `RER0000000` or `REQ10000000`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$sql_query = "SELECT CONCAT('REQ',LPAD(CAST(SUBSTR(request_id,4,7) AS UNSIGNED)+1,7,'0')) ORDER BY request_id DESC LIMIT 1"
```

Answer (score 3):

You can increment strings in perl:

```
if ($x lt 'REQ9999999') {
    $nextRequestId = $x;
    $nextRequestId++;
} else {
    // you ran out of request ids
}
```

(if you don't check for `REQ9999999` you will end up with `RER0000000` at some point)

Comment: This is good way to achieve want i wanted to. Well want to know is there any consequences of this approach?

Comment: I've already described the major consequence, that you have to watch that your increment does not roll into the alphabetical portion of the string. Other than that, there might be a slight performance penalty, though I believe it would be negligible compared to the performance cost of the query you execute to fetch the current max request id.

Answer (score 1):

use sprintf to left pad the string with 0s

```
sprintf("REQ%08d", $x)
```